# Can I use Microsoft Graph to create Outlook-Add ins?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin

Can Microsoft Graph documentation be used in Outlook Add-ins? For example, can I use node to create the add-in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Graph, the Outlook REST APIs and Office for JavaScript in web add-ins for Outlook.  You don't need a specific IDE or web server to develop them.  See here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/